# Excel - Removing part of a connecting line in a scatterplot? Editing the legend?

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I'm working on creating a reaction norm plot in Excel. I used the 'scatterplot with markers and lines' function as a base. The plot compares 'Lineage' with 'Average Day 21 Frond Count.' I'm nearly finished with it, but have two things I need to fix, and can't figure out how:

1. I need to remove the long blue line connecting the square at point (SP43, ~100) and the triangle at point (SP01, ~80).
2. I need to edit the legend so that the label for the square says '2n' and the label for the triangle says '4n.'

I need to have this graph finished before 3/7/24 at 4:00pm. Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Link to a screenshot of the graph and data as they are right now:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/70ypA.png)

I have no idea where to even start on deleting a section of the blue line connecting the data points. For the problem with the legend, I tried accessing the editor for the legend, but couldn't find any places where I could edit the actual text within the legend - just format how it looked (font, color, etc.).

Comment: It looks as though all the data is in one series - suggest you need to have it in two series to get rid of the blue line.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't time to give more information unfortunately but your setup should be something like this where since it has category labels I am just using a line chart:

[image]